# How do I clear the result message data from a SQL query while in the middle of the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am currently using MS SQL Server 2008.

I have a stored procedure that sends an email using sp_send_dbmail. sp_send_dbmail prints "Mail Queued" to the result message. I need to erase this from the result message. Is there a way to fully clear what has been printed to the result message or to mute "print" commands like this from populating at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@exclude_query_output` argument suppresses it. By default is set to 0 so you just set it to 1.

More information at documentation: [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'm blind. I thought I had looked all the parameters over, but just lumped that setting in with the @query params. Thanks.